# Element with shadow root breaks text selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, shadow-dom

It appears that in Firefox shadow root text contents are not user-selectable like any other text on the page.

Demo: execute the snippet below and press Ctrl + A in the result frame. Here's what happens:

[image]

```js
let wShadow = document.querySelector('#with-shadow-root')

let p = document.createElement('p')
p.textContent = 'With shadow root'

wShadow.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
wShadow.shadowRoot.appendChild(p)
```

```html
<div>
  Some text.
  <p id="with-shadow-root"></p>
  Some more text.
</div>

<div>
  Some text.
  <p>Without shadow root.</p>
  Some more text.
</div>
```

I wish the *With shadow root* text fragment to be selected as well.

**How to make this work in Firefox? Is there some CSS property that controls this behavior?**

Bonus question: is Firefox behaving correctly here as per the spec? Or is it a bug? (I can't find any bug about this in Bugzilla).

I tried setting display to inline and the `user-select` CSS property to no avail.

Just to show the same also happens with custom elements, in both shadow modes:

```js
class MyPOpen extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.text = document.createTextNode('With open shadow root');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.text);
  }
}

customElements.define('my-p-closed', MyPOpen);

class MyPClosed extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'closed'
    });
    this.text = document.createTextNode('With closed shadow root');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.text);
  }
}

customElements.define('my-p-open', MyPClosed);
```

```css
my-p-open, my-p-closed { display: block; }
```

```html
<div>
  Some text.
  <my-p-open></my-p-open>
  <my-p-closed></my-p-closed>
  Some more text.
</div>

<div>
  Some text.
  <p>Without shadow root.</p>
  Some more text.
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think shadow roots are meant to be used without custom elements.

Comment: Not sure about that statement @connexo. But yeah, I'm actually seeing this behavior with a CE with shadow root. Here I wanted to posted a minimal reproducible example, hence I stripped the custom element part, as it doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Trying to select the text using the mouse is even more irritating.

Comment: Yeah, it is. One element like that on the page and user can't reliably select text anymore. I was surprised nobody seemed to notice/care so far (at least I haven't found any questions/bugs about it).

Comment: I just filed a report at bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1587724. Great find!

Comment: I was going to wait a day or two to see if I get any answers, and then file a bug ;) Cheers!

Comment: this behavior isn't really a surprise for me as it behaves the same like iframe. If you add an iframe inside your code you will not be able to select it's content using Ctrl+A if the focus is outside (chrome will select the whole iframe). A shadow-dom is alsmot similar to an iframe

Comment: That works in Chrome so I suppose it's a Firefox bug, too.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It seems to behave like that in Firefox only though. Webkit browser seem to be more "relaxed" and allow text selection that crossed shadow boundary.

Comment: yes and it seems to match the behavior of iframe. In chrome the iframe will be selected and not in FF

Comment: I see. Nice spot @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [bug report I filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1587724) in reaction to the findings in this question has been closed as a duplicate of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1545367).

The last comments on that 2nd bug report are shedding some light on this:

> Q: Too late for a fix in 70 but as we're seeing some duplicates, could you take another look and maybe aim for a fix in 72? Or is this part of some bigger project?
>
> A: Implementing different Selection handling when Shadow DOM is enabled is a massive task, and that work is ongoing.
> (Selection handling with Shadow DOM isn't really specified)

So to answer your question, by the looks of it text selection handling in conjunction with shadow DOM seems to be a) unspecified territory, and b) kind of difficult to implement.

At least there's agreement on that the current handling in Firefox is not what they want it to be.

Comment: so it's like a bug but it's not their fault :-/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this firefox bug too (still not fixed in firefox 102, three years later). But I discovered something that mitigates the problem for me: make sure the text is inside a block inside your shadowroot (easiest way to achieve this is with `<style>:host {display: block;}</style>`).

Just run the code snippet below and compare the three sections. In current firefox (102), it's impossible to select all text with the mouse in the first section. As soon as you hit the empty space between paragraphs, your selection is reset. In the second section, `display: block` is applied and it's possible to select all the text, as long as you don't go outside the shadowroot. The last section, without shadowroot, is included for reference - text selection should work normally.

```js
const lipsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
const lipsum3 = `<p>${lipsum}</p><p>${lipsum}</p><p>${lipsum}</p>`;

class LipsumInline extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<h1>Shadowroot - inline</h1>${lipsum3}`;
    }
}

class LipsumBlock extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style>:host { display: block; }</style>
        <h1>Shadowroot - Block</h1>${lipsum3}`;
    }
}

customElements.define('lipsum-inline', LipsumInline);
customElements.define('lipsum-block', LipsumBlock);

window.onload = () => {
    const elt = document.querySelector('body');

    const lipsumInline = document.createElement('lipsum-inline');
    elt.appendChild(lipsumInline);
    
    const lipsumBlock = document.createElement('lipsum-block');
    elt.appendChild(lipsumBlock);
    
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = `<h1>Span - no shadowroot</h1>${lipsum3}`;
    elt.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/"/>
    <title>Selection bug - minimal test case</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```